# How can I show cppcheck output in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode9, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I want to display `cppcheck` output directly in the Xcode Issue Navigator. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple script that you can add as a `Run Script Phase` in your `Build Phases` in Xcode:

```
#!/bin/bash
srcDir=src
if which cppcheck >/dev/null; then
cppcheck -j 4 --enable=all --inline-suppr $srcDir 2>cppcheck.txt 1>/dev/null
pwd=$(pwd)
sed "s|\[|${pwd}/|" cppcheck.txt | sed 's|\]: |: warning: |'
rm cppcheck.txt
else
echo "warning: cppcheck not installed, install here: http://brewformulas.org/Cppcheck"
fi
```